# Create image on fly with nodejs and canvas

Tags: javascript, node.js, image, canvas, on-the-fly

I am doing a web application using nodejs. I have a form where a user can select an image and enter some extra text data. With this information I have to create an image with the text entered by the user embedded in a fixed position. This image has to be created at the time they are completed fields, with the aim that when the end of the process, the user can see the generated image before saving it.
I studied this [canvas](https://github.com/Automattic/node-canvas) but I do not see how to implement it on the fly.

Clarified that's the first thing I'm going to make with nodejs so I have no experience on the platform.

I can do what I need using canvas? How else you can achieve something like this?
Thank you!!

Comment: I have to save the image in the server, but the client have to see before this

Comment: I am using expressjs like template engine. Maybe i can use another engine? more powerfull?

Comment: I changed the approach of the problem. I use an canvas html5 now. 
Now my problem is how save that image. 
I get the image like a base64 encode image but i don't know how save this image in nodejs.
I had read about using multer, but can't get it done.

Thanks